# external graphic card for pc(windows)

Tags: graphics-cards, performance, rendering

After I invested on a laptop to start graphic designing I ended up finding out that AMD wasn't good for it and that my computer's power isn't enough(AMD doesn't support openGL render and I have just an i5 processor in my computer).
So I was wondering if it was possible to install an external GPU on my pc. I am just a simple end use with not so much knowledge on hardware, and I was wondering if external nvidia graphic cards are available that would run via USB ports in my PC(windows 7).
If not, what would be a work around for me that would provide me a similar performance of an nvidia graphic card and would support high and fast rendering(for 3D graphics,{specifically I'm using blender- cycles})?
(I'm using a dell inspiron laptop.)

Comment: Peripherals won't help you in this situation because USB bandwidth bottlenecks high-speed devices. You'll have to upgrade the video card inside your laptop.

Comment: @Adam, I found something about a thunderbolt. Is it also for windows?

Comment: Yes, but even Thunderbolt 3 will bottleneck a modern external video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not, external graphic cards do not run via anything lower than USB 3.0.  In addition that USB port has to be a thunderbolt port in order for an exteranl GPU to be supproted through it. This is simply because an older USB port doesn't have enough bandwidth to support the communication between a GPU and your PC, and also because it doesn't connect to the appropriate port on the motherboard. Thunderbolt ports however are based on PCI-E technology which is the same, as the one used by desktop graphics cards to communicate with the computer. Hence, if your laptop supports thunderbolt you would be able to purchase an external GPU chassis (like the one offered by RazerBlade), as well as a GPU that would convert PCI-E to thinderbolt, and plug into the proper port on your laptop. We would have to know the exact model number of your laptop to tell if it is equipped by a thunderbolt port.

Comment: it is a dell inspiron 3537 model no. .

Comment: Your laptop does not support thunderbolt, therefore you will not be able to utilize an external GPU. As of what @Adam has said about switching out the laptop's dedicated graphics card - it is extremely rare that dedicated laptop GPUs are replaceable, and it is even more rare that they are upgradeable. Most likely you will have to replace your laptop to swap your graphics card.